# Testing Index of String Array in c++?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char str[80];
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Enter the String ";
    gets(str);
    for (int j=0;str[j]!='\0';j++)
    if (str[i]=='A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U')
    i++;
    cout<<"Number of vowels is: "<<i;



}
```

Here i am check element in String for Vowel, can anyone please suggest alternate method for this? I need to count number of vowels in string.

This code is working perfect for me, just need to find alternate method where i don't have to type too much "||" and 'a' and 'A' differently.

Comment: Is it not working? Do you have a problem? an error?

Comment: I would suggest a method that counts lowercase vowels too. Oh, and use `str[j]`.

Comment: @talnicolas No, it's not working. I count 3 real errors, several potential problems and a number of smaller issues, like the mixing of C with C++, the absence of a return statement etc.

Comment: @LaimeNekurzeme re your edit: take a look at toupper() and the like. But the way you changed your program makes it even worse. The vowel counter cannot be the same variable as the string indexer!

Comment: Fixed Now! Thanks, i messed it up!

Comment: @Mr Lister According to new C++ standards, there is no need to return statement. that's what my teacher is teaching me.

Comment: OK, so then tell me what the return value of your program is. Is it the same as what your teacher tells you it should be?

Comment: @Mr Lister, my program is not returning anything. After successfully working. It will automatically return 0 to os. It is printing number of vowels on screen

Comment: Sorry, if i got it wrong, i am still a kid in this programming world.

Comment: @MrLister: the OP is right, in C++, `main` returns 0 if there is no return statement. This is different from C.

Comment: OK, OK. The program does have a return value, but I was checking if Laime knew how to find out what it is. Laime, ook up `exit status`, `$?` or `errorlevel`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (str[i]=='A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U')
```

this is wrong

should be like this:

```
if(str[i]=='A' || str[i]=='E'||str[i]=='I'||str[i]=='O'||str[i]=='U')
```

and also take care of case sensitiveness

Answer (score 4):

```
str[i]=='A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U'
```

always returns true, because `'E'` is always true. You're looking for

```
strchr("AEIOU", str[j])
```

Note the `j`, you got the loop variable wrong.

(Also, in C++, you'll want to use `iostreams` and `getline` instead of `cstdio` and `fgets`.)

Comment: Why 'E' is always true? Please throw some light on it.

Comment: @LaimeNekurzeme: `'E'` is not zero, and any non-zero value is considered true in a boolean context.

Comment: if 'E' is not zero , how can i test for vowel? I am not using it in context to any Boolean. I am using it to test the character in string.

Answer (score 2):

A more C++-ish solution:

```
std::string vowels("aAeEiIoOuU");
for (int j=0;str[j]!='\0';j++)
{
   if ( vowels.find(str[j]) != std::string::npos )
   i++;
}
```

Comment: `str[i]` should be `str[j]` in the loop condition.

Comment: @larsmans ah, I changed the index inside the loop, but forgot the outside one. http://alltheragefaces.com/img/faces/png/disappointed-so-close-freddie-mercury.png

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - you have a small bug. `std::string::find` always returns a value greater than zero. Prefer: `vowels.find(str[j]) != std::string::npos`

Comment: @Rob it actually returns `-1` if the letter is not found, but `npos` is much better, agreed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - no, actually it returns `npos` (defined as `(size_t)-1`), which is a *positive* number. Your previous version produced the wrong answer.

Comment: Terrible, slow, useless. Consider using a switch or at least memchr rather than unnecessary dynamic memory + O(log n) * O(n) solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
inline bool is_vowel(char a)
{
    a=std::tolower(a);
    switch(a)
    {
    case 'a':        case 'e':
    case 'i':        case 'o':
    case 'u':
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "enter text" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    int vowel=std::count_if(line.begin(), line.end(), is_vowel);
    std::cout << "Number of vowels: " << vowel << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to post use of `std::count_if()` as never spotted you had used it.

Comment: yep count_if is really the right too for the job here, my predicate could be improved i think, but it is a damn sight better than the loops and other C like hacks listed

Answer (score 0):

Or use a table:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  char list_v[256] = { 0 };
  list_v['a'] = list_v['e'] = list_v['i'] = list_v['o'] = list_v['u'] = 1;
  list_v['A'] = list_v['E'] = list_v['I'] = list_v['O'] = list_v['U'] = 1;
  std::string str = "a sentence here";
  uint32_t cnt = 0;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
     cnt += list_v[str[i]];
  std::cout << "found " << cnt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

or use map for the same purpose, or a c++ array/vector, people don't like c arrays here. This only works for ASCII of course.

Comment: This is only good if your CPU frequency is about the same as memory access. Otherwise it is slow as crap once data is not in the CPU cache upon calling a function. Lookup table is only good if tradeoffs are alternative implementations are taking longer than memory access latency... So in general - avoid using lookup tables unless necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Way? or syntax?

i think its a syntax error.. it should be like

`if(str[i]=='A' || str[i]=='E'||str[i]=='I'||str[i]=='O'||str[i]=='U')`

If you are asking about a better way, i don't think there is any.. 
You are doing in O(n) complexity, which is good enough i guess.! Even if you use hashing, you'll have to hash all the n characters in a string..